# Force Content-Type to application/json with mode no-cors

Tags: reactjs, post, content-type

i want to force the content-type to application/json but i have a mode "no-cors" and actually the return for content-type is : text/plain;charset=UTF-8 its the same when i pass the headers so i don't know how do this.

I have already tried to use fetch or Axios, the URL is in HTTP and i work in local so maybe it's the problem?
I have tried on Postman, that work great.

```
     fetch('http://link', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            redirect: 'follow',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "cluster_id" : [],
                "surname" :["albert"],
                "gender" :[],

            }),
        }).then((result) => {
            this.setState({ allClient: result.data }, () => {
                this.setState({ load: true })
                console.log(this.state.allClient)
        })
```

So, i want to have content type: application/json and not Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned CORS and localhost, but I don't know that your issue is with either of them based on the information provided.

The `content-type` header specifies the MIME type for the body following the header. For your request, it's the type of the request body. For the response, it's the type for the response body.

You're correctly setting the content type of your request, and telling the server what you're looking for w/ the `accept` header, but ultimately it's up to the server-side to set the header. If you control the server, you can adjust as needed, but otherwise you're stuck consuming what is being served.

Comment: I don't have the control of the server. But why in Postman i can collect all datas ? And this API is call by other website and that work fine

Comment: @KérianPelat If you are in a browser context and, as you say, CORS is not instrumented on the server to be permissive, then you wouldn't be able to access the Content-Type header. Is a preflight request being sent (as shown in your network panel of your dev tool inspector)?